# How to stop Let'sEncrypt checking my domain for acme-challenge

Tags: lets-encrypt

Sorry if this question already asked before, but I can't found solution for my issue.
Previously I have site on Webmin server and use Let'sEncrypt SSL for the domain.

Now, I moved my site to Google Cloud Run. But the Let'sEncrypt engine keep check my site for acme-challange regularly every 30minutes.
Even after I delete site from my Webmin server, I still keep check my site for acme-challenge.
This make my Google Cloud Run cost increased.

[LetsEncrypt acme-challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg3Z4.png)

Do you know how to stop the LetsEncrypt engine checking my domain?

Answer (score 2):

You have an ACME client with HTTP validation still running somewhere and trying to get a TLS certificate for your domain. You need to find this ACME client and disable it.

Comment: Hmm, I see.. In progress trying to find it and disable it.

Comment: I have turn off my previous server to prevent ACME client requesting for certificate, but until now it did not stop.    
Do you know, is this ACME http validation check request comes from LetsEncrypt website or from my server?    
And if I let it reply with 404, how long this ACME engine will still check my domain until it stop by itself?    
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Requests to /.well-known/ are coming from Let's Encrypt servers. If you return 404 they can stop for some period due to the rate-limiting of failing requests on Let's Encrypt side but they will resume if your ACME client is still running and requesting a certificate for your domain.